# Получение адреса хоста WCF C#

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, tcp

Сделал простое приложение WCF, все прописал в файле конфигурации

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="TelemetryService.TelemetryData">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/IContract/" 
              binding="netHttpBinding"
              contract="GeneralContract.IContract"/>
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Data">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

</system.serviceModel>
```

Все работает, но вот хочу в консоли вывести текущий адрес: "Сервис с таким то адресом запущен" 
Вроде такая мелочь, а не могу к этому тегу обратиться.
Есть вроде коллекция:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Data));
host.Description.Endpoints;
```

А вот как мне просто из нее строку с адресом формата http://localhost:8000/IContract/ получить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал вот так.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < host.Description.Endpoints.Count; i++)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(host.Description.Endpoints[i].Address.ToString());
            }
```

И все заработало. Если несколько точек, можно сделать сравнение с именем сервиса.